# M1 Monterey install rgdal problems

Tags: gdal, mac

Can't install rgdal, sf etc however my necessary libs are installed like gdal, proj, geos.

I do not know what the problem is.

> install.packages("rgdal", type = "source") trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rgdal_1.5-32.tar.gz' Content
> type 'application/x-gzip' length 4469369 bytes (4.3 MB)
> ================================================== downloaded 4.3 MB
>
> - installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
>   ** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   ** using staged installation configure: R_HOME: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources configure: CC: clang
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 configure: CXX: clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++14 configure: CFLAGS: -Wall -g -O2 configure: CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/include configure: CXXFLAGS: -Wall -g -O2 configure: LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib configure: LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib configure: CXX11 is: clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13, CXX11STD is: -std=gnu++11 configure: CXX is: clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 configure: C++11
>   support available configure: rgdal: 1.5-32 checking for
>   /usr/bin/svnversion... no configure: svn revision: 1176 checking for
>   gdal-config... /opt/homebrew/bin/gdal-config checking gdal-config
>   usability... yes configure: GDAL: 3.5.1 checking GDAL version >=
>   1.11.4... yes checking GDAL version <= 2.5 or >= 3.0... yes checking GDAL: linking with --libs only... no checking GDAL: linking with
>   --libs and --dep-libs... no ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.5.1_2/lib/libgdal.dylib, building for
>   macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_GDALAllRegister",
>   referenced from:
>   _main in gdal_test-a23254.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation) ld: warning: directory not found for
>   option '-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.14_3/lib' ld: library not
>   found for -lcrypto clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation) configure: Install failure: compilation
>   and/or linkage problems. configure: error: GDALAllRegister not found
>   in libgdal. ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
> - removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/rgdal’

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the solution. The problem is with the arm based versions of gdal and etc. When R tries to install these packages they are looking for an intel version (probably the package is not ready and fully compatible with arm).

To solve the issue:

1. Install rosetta 2
2. Create a terminal copy in your applications which is going to run with rosetta 2 (you can tick on Terminal - Copy info page)
3. remove arm based homebrew (also clean folders and junk that is left behind in /opt/homebrew)
4. install intel based homebrew in the second rosetta terminal (which brew should show /usr/...)
5. install pkg-config, proj, geos, and gdal with intel based homebrew
6. restart R and install rgdal and all the gdal based packages you need